# React app functions correctly on local but not on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, api, github-pages

I pushed my one page React project to github pages. While the page appears, it doesn't function correctly. It's a basic app where users search through an API and then when they click on a movie it is added to their watchlist. However when I enter my query through the search, nothing happens as opposed to local host where the movies appear and everything functions correctly.

When I inspect it via the console, I get the following error:
The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "watchlater",
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/watchlater/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there something else I need to change? I followed the instructions here(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) to publish it on gh-pages but the actual functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Did you use http instead of https for any of the resources?

Comment: Use the Security tab in developer tools. Should show you exactly which resource is insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error is called "mixed-content" You are trying to access via "HTTP" on an "HTTPS" site because this vulnerable to eavesdropping attacks by hackers and this is a violation.

https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my API call had HTTP instead of HTTPS. I changed it to HTTPS and it now works.